# LibGDX Multiply Vector2 with float value

Tags: java, vector, libgdx

Is there a way to multiply a Vector2 with a float value? I used to do this in XNA to calculate movement by multiplying a normalized direction vector with a velocity float. This pretty much is the last step in my code to make things work but there does not seem a multiply function for a Vector2 that accepts a float value. I could just mulltiply x and y manually but there should be a method for this i don't know about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html :

```
scl
public Vector2 scl(float x,
                   float y)
Multiplies this vector by a scalar
Returns:
This vector for chaining
```

So I guess it's called "scale". If you want to multiply the entire vector, just use the same value for x and y.